# Heroku add remote error on UBUNTU

Tags: git, ubuntu, heroku, deployment, heroku-cli

I'm spending all day trying to figure out why this error happens in UBUNTU.

I'm tryng to add the Heroku remote git to my existing repo in my local machine that runs Ubuntu.

so, when i run this:

```
heroku git:remote -a myapp
```

I get this error:

```
ENOENT: spawn git ENOENT
```

Im logged in with heroku-cli. When I set "heroku apps" it shows my app there.

No success with sudo command also.

So, what could be wrong here?

Comment: Seems like a [popular](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bheroku%5D+git+ENOENT) problem.

Comment: Search didn't help here